# JQuery Ajax POST object to .NET controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This seems to be something that should be relatively easy to accomplish but I'm struggling to spot why it doesn't work. All the posts and documentation I read suggest that it should "just work" - but it doesn't.

In short, I want to POST an object to a .NET controller using JQuery AJAX.

The object/class I want to POST is currently very simple (it will gain properties once I've got it working). When I run this, the controller isn't hit (at least not in the debugger) and I see in my console window the error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Namespace.Models.DTOs.SearchParameters' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

But as far as I can see, I'm not passing an array.

C# Class

```
public class SearchParameters
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

C# Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/example")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Run([FromBody]SearchParameters? searchParameters)
{
    ...do stuff
}
```

JavaScript object

```
let searchParameters = {
    name: "M"
};
```

Ajax options

```
{
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(searchParameters),
    dataSrc: 'data',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/example"
}
```

Comment: Is `JSON.stringify` necessary here?  I've always just used the object directly.

Comment: I don't know anymore. I didn't think so, but as the post suggest, I can't get it to work so I've been trying all manner of things. Adding that was one of the things I tried because that's what another post on here suggested. Removing it doesn't help.

Comment: Use network debugging tools to confirm that jquery is sending your data in the `body` and not in the `url`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you spend hours trying to solve it and then as soon as you post on here you suddenly get it working. The only change I needed to make was to capitalise the property name in the JSON object. The JSON.stringify does seem to be required though.

Comment: To confirm: it needs `data` to be a json string because your `contentType:` tells it that you're passing a json string.   The two need to match.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So what contentType do you use when you want to pass a plain javascript object?

Comment: None, leave it as default. See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If I don't add a contentType (of "application/json"), then the controller doesn't serve the request. In the console window I get the following error. So it seems that you do have to provide the contentType. Unless there is something I need to change on my controller?

status: 415
title: "Unsupported Media Type"
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13"

Comment: Depends on your server.  Not specifying the content type is the same as specifying a content type of the default value.  If your server doesn't access that content type then you need to provide another.